# embed.swf makes Firefox window unresizable

Tags: html, flash, firefox, swfobject

Can someone tell me, why the following html code makes a firefox window (on windows7) unresizable?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Flash</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    swfobject.embedSWF("Menu.swf", "flashdiv", "100%", "100%", "10");
});
</script>
<style>
html,body,#flashdiv
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><div id="flashdiv"></div></body>
</html>
```

live testcase: http://www.embege.com/misc/ff.html

edit: i already tried to disable all addons. also i tried the firefox beta, but the window size is still locked when i am at this page.

Comment: What do you mean by `makes a firefox window unresizable` ? Nothing inside the browser can control that.

Comment: but it does. if i grab the edge of the browser window and start to drag. it snaps right back to its original position

Comment: No problems for me. I am running ff 13 in my W7

Comment: No problems for me running FF14 on OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a known bug with Firefox and Adobe Flash Player for a certain combination of Firefox and Flash Player. The bug has been filed both with Adobe and Firefox, you can read the details about this bug in the [Mozilla Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765788#c34).

If you are interested in the technical details of the bug, here's a description of what's causing the problem:

> Jeromie reports that the problem is Flash releasing the Mouse Capture
>   too early. As far as I can see, this is correct. Flash also seems to
>   be eating our WM_CAPTURECHANGED messages, these are not filtering up
>   to the Firefox WndProc. With Flash 11.4, we are getting these
>   messages. So, not only is mouse capture being released early, we are
>   not being told about it, so we can't try to grab the mouse capture
>   ourselves (although this would be inadvisable anyway).

The bug has been [reported as closed in the Adobe Flash Player bug database](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3217427), upgrading to the latest version of Firefox and Flash Player should solve the problem. If that's not he case for you, try to follow the steps described in [comment #58 of the Mozilla bug entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=765788#c58).